# Will Outlook 2010 let me know when it is time to send a Follow-Up note?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I think I must be a follow-up fool. The way I'm using Outlook 2010's follow-up function seems foolish.

I send emails to many business prospects asking them for their guidelines for receiving business proposals. I flag these outgoing emails to follow-up in a week in case they don't reply.

When I send the emails, there's a good percentage that I know won't reply--for whatever reason--and I must follow-up... thus the reason I set the flags for a one-week follow-up.

Now, when I DO get a reply from someone--let's call him Joe-- I click the follow-up flag on Joe's message right away because I need to prepare a proposal for him. After doing so, I go into my For Follow-Up Folder. Since there are so many For Follow-Ups in this folder, I need to actually search for the email I sent to Joe since it would take too long to find the email I sent to him, otherwise. When I find it, I REMOVE the flag on the ORIGINAL inquiry emails that I sent to Joe.

To be clear, I'm getting replies to dozens of emails... but dozens more don't reply without me following up.

**The problem is**, I'm jumping back and forth and back and forth from my In-Box to my For-Follow-Up folder over and over and over, every time I do receive a response to my email.

Isn't there some way to more easily have Outlook "know" that the person replied... or somehow mark that I DID reply (after I send them the proposal) and thus clear the flag for me and make the whole flag-clearing process easier? I can't imagine that this is the most effective way to do what I'm doing.

I hope this was clear. Many thanks for anyone who can shed some light on this for me!

Comment: I was able to find a few add-ins that claim to provide this kind of function, but I think plain Outlook will not do that.  Search the web for `outlook follow up add in`.